# Ajax function is not display xml data on some mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I tried to view XML data in html. This project works fine on desktop browsers but does not work on some mobile browsers. I feel like the issue is obviously but I don't know what to do. Please help.

```html
<div class="row" id="xmldata"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser2
  });
});

function xmlParser2(xml) {
  xml = $(xml).children();
  let total = $(xml).children().length;

  $(xml).children().each(function(idx, index, item) {
    let tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
    let nextIdx = idx + 1;
    let prevIdx = idx - 1;
    //to make cyclic
    nextIdx = nextIdx == total ? 0 : nextIdx;
    prevIdx = prevIdx == -1 ? (total - 1) : prevIdx;

    let image = '<img style="background-image:url(' + $(this).find("image").text() + ')"' + '" />';
    let image2 = '<div><img src="' + $(this).find("image").text() + '" width="100%" alt="' + '" />' + '</div>';
    let head = '<div>' + $(this).find("head").text() + '</div>';
    let html = `<div class="col-sm-4 random reveal" id="random">
      <div class="thumbnail randomdiv3">
        <a href="#${tag + idx}" id="openModalBtn">
          <div>${image}</div>
          <h5>${head}</h5>
        </a>
      </div>
     </div>`;
    $("#xmldata").append(html);
  });
}
```

Comment: whats the error exactly if you debug mobile version ?

Comment: Is there an error in the console ? You should try to debug with an emulator or just try to see what's going on with the chrome integrate mobile debugger

Comment: You are using `let` and template literals ``..${variable}..`` that are part of ES6. Make sure the browser supports these.